# Telegraph JS simple button with markup not working

Tags: typescript, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I am tying to build a telegram bot using [telegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/) library on a node typescript project.

I want to create a simple button when a user types a command. I tried using examples from the [documentation](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/5588e0599769377468828f657f7125acbb7870ac/docs/examples/keyboard-bot.js#L61-L125) (from this question [How to create messages with reply buttons](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/discussions/1450)). But it is not working. I have multiple ts errors:

- `Argument of type 'Markup & InlineKeyboardMarkup' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtraReplyMessage | undefined'.`
- `Property 'callback' does not exist on type '(text: string, hide?: boolean | undefined) => Button'.`

Here is my code:

```
import TelegrafJS from 'telegraf';

const { Markup } = TelegrafJS;

const { TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN } = process.env;
if (!TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN) throw new Error('Required env variable missing: TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN');

const bot = new TelegrafJS.Telegraf(TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN);

// WORKS
bot.command('test0', (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply('Test 0', {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [{ text: 'Next', callback_data: 'next' }],
      ],
    },
  });
});

// NOT WORKING
bot.command('keyboard', (ctx) => ctx.reply(
  'Keyboard',
  Markup.inlineKeyboard([
    Markup.button.callback('First option', 'first'),
    Markup.button.callback('Second option', 'second'),
  ]),
));

bot.launch();
```

[image: ts error telegraf button]

It works without using Markup but I would prefer to use it. How Can I fix this errors ?